# Same changes to multiple packages Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have made a game for Android and I have two, practically, identical packages. The only thing that separates them is that one is containing adsense. So now if I want to make some changes and continue develop my game I want to make it to both versions of the game without too much work. How can I do that, or does anyone have a better idea? Because I must have two different packages to be able to upload to different versions (free and non-free) on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

Use a library project for the main part of the game, with two app projects to handle the differences: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects